# with spring 3 annotations, jsr303 getting Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'dataForm'

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, attributes, request

Implementing a simple jsr303 validation using spring 3 with annotations and I am getting the following result when the post finds missing elements:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'dataForm' available as request attribute

The controller looks like so:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes
@RequestMapping( "/dataentry.html" )
public class EnterDataController
{
  @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET )
  public String enterNewDataHandler( Map model )
  {
    DataEntryForm dataForm = new DataEntryForm();
    model.put( "dataForm", dataForm );
    return ( "dataentry" );
  }

  @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.POST )
  public String addData( @Valid DataEntryForm dataForm,
                           BindingResult          result,
                           Map                    model )
  {
    if ( result.hasErrors() ) { return ( "dataentry" ); }

    ... code for saving data ...
  }
}
```

The form looks like so:

```
public class DataEntryForm
{
  @NotNull
  private Double dataAmount;

  @NotNull
  @Temporal(value=TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date dataDate;

  ... sets and gets ...
}
```

The jsp form section looks like so:

```
<form:form method="post"
           commandName="dataForm"
           action="dataentry.html">
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td><form:label path=dataAmount">Data</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="dataAmount"/></td>
    <td><div class="error"><form:errors path="dataAmount"/></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><form:label path="dataDate">Date</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="dataDate"/></td>
    <td><div class="error"><form:errors path="dataDate"/></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Add Data"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form:form>
```

I am implementing a standard spring return type of String for the logical view name.  Here is the full stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'dataForm' available as request attribute
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.dataentry_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(dataentry_jsp.java:287)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.dataentry_jsp._jspService(dataentry_jsp.java:114)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:927)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.layout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f3(layout_jsp.java:287)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.layout_jsp._jspService(layout_jsp.java:128)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Any suggestions?  And, is there any docs that describe in detail what happens under the hood with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have had this problem before. I believe that in addition to using `@Valid` you must also use `@ModelAttribute("dataForm")` so it knows how to map your form to your DataEntryForm object.

```
  @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.POST )
  public String addData( @ModelAttribute("dataForm") @Valid DataEntryForm dataForm,
                       BindingResult          result,
                       Map                    model )
  {
      if ( result.hasErrors() ) { return ( "dataentry" ); }

      ... code for saving data ...
  }
```

It looks a little ugly. I kind of wish that the two annotations could be combined somehow.

Comment: I implemented that suggestion earlier and it did indeed work however a couple of sample apps that I tried, which did not use @ModelAttribute, ran fine with no errors so there is something going on here that still does not make sense.  Thanks

Comment: @sldahlin: agree with you, the modelattribute in controller is no need. But if you don't use model attribute, you must by some way show Spring how to parse your object. Try adding  modelAttribute="dataAmount" in your form tag

Comment: I know it's more than 4 months old, but this answer solved my problem, thanks!