# Spring MVC: Error with form tag and command

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am programming with the Spring Framework and I'm desperate after the following error is displayed while processing the jsp in the form tag (line 2).

**Error:**

```
    ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag - Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:164)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:151)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.administracion.habilidades_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005finput_005f0(habilidades_jsp.java:1081)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.administracion.habilidades_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fform_005f0(habilidades_jsp.java:996)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.administracion.habilidades_jsp._jspService(habilidades_jsp.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:477)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
22-jun-2012 14:16:40 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para servlet jsp lanzó una excepción
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:164)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:151)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.administracion.habilidades_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005finput_005f0(habilidades_jsp.java:1081)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.administracion.habilidades_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fform_005f0(habilidades_jsp.java:996)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.administracion.habilidades_jsp._jspService(habilidades_jsp.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:477)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
22-jun-2012 14:16:40 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [appServlet] en el contexto con ruta [/tryp] lanzó la excepción [Ha sucedido una excepción al procesar la página JSP /WEB-INF/views/administracion/habilidades.jsp en línea 363

360:                        <div class="control-group">
361:                            <label class="control-label" for="codigo"><s:message code="codigo"/></label>
362:                            <div class="controls">
363:                                <f:input type="text" class="span1" name="codigo" path="codigo" />
364:                            </div>
365:                        </div>
366: 


Stacktrace:] con causa raíz
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:164)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:151)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.administracion.habilidades_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005finput_005f0(habilidades_jsp.java:1081)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.administracion.habilidades_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fform_005f0(habilidades_jsp.java:996)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.administracion.habilidades_jsp._jspService(habilidades_jsp.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:477)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

**My jsp fragment:**

```
<div class="modal-body">
            <f:form method="POST" modalAttribute="habilidad" class="form-horizontal em" id="formHabilidad">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="codigo"><s:message code="codigo"/></label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <f:input type="text" class="span1" name="codigo" path="codigo" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="descripcion"><s:message code="descripcion"/></label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <f:input type="text" class="span3" name="codigo" path="descripcion"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </fieldset>
            </f:form>
        </div>
```

**Part of my controller:**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/habilidades", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getHabilidades(Model model) {
      model.addAttribute("habilidades",aService.getHabilidades(new User()));
      model.addAttribute("habilidad",new Habilidad());
      return "administracion/habilidades";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/JSONHabilidades", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public @ResponseBody List<Habilidad> getJSONTHabilidades(Model model) {   
      return aService.getHabilidades(new User());
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/habilidades", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody Habilidad postHabilidades(@ModelAttribute Habilidad habilidad, HttpSession session) {
      habilidad.setEscala((Escala)session.getAttribute("escala"));
      return  aService.saveOrUpdate(habilidad);
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteHabilidad", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody Habilidad deleteHabilidad(Habilidad habilidad) {
    return  aService.delete(habilidad);
  }
```

**My entity Habilidad.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TTR_HABILIDAD")
public class Habilidad implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "G3", sequenceName = "SEQ_HABILIDAD_ID_HABILIDAD")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "G3")
    @Column(name="ID_HABILIDAD", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22)
    private Long idHabilidad;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 256)
    private String codigo;

    @Column(length = 256)
    private String descripcion;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Empleado
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="TTR_HABILIDAD_EMP"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="ID_HABILIDAD")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="ID_EMPLEADO")
            }
        )
    private Set<Empleado> empleados;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Escala
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ESCALA", nullable = false)
    private Escala escala;


    public Habilidad() {
    }

    public Long getIdHabilidad() {
        return this.idHabilidad;
    }

    public void setIdHabilidad(Long idHabilidad) {
        this.idHabilidad = idHabilidad;
    }

    public String getCodigo() {
        return this.codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return this.descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public Escala getEscala() {
        return this.escala;
    }

    public void setEscala(Escala escala) {
        this.escala = escala;
    }


}
```

**My entity HabilidadDAO.java:**

```
public interface HabilidadDAO extends GenericDAO<Habilidad, Long> {
    public List<Habilidad> getHabilidades(User u);

}
```

**My entity HabilidadDAOImpl.java**

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class HabilidadDAOImpl extends GenericDAOImpl<Habilidad, Long>  implements HabilidadDAO {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Habilidad> getHabilidades(User u){
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT h FROM Habilidad h");
        return q.getResultList();
    }

}
```

**EDIT: The bug has been fixed but the controller does not obtain the values ​​of the inputs. To fix this error: I have to change the attribute modalAttribute to modelAtrribute.**

Comment: -Can you please add the type of your controller?

Comment: also what is the type of `aService` and the return type of `saveOrUpdate`

Comment: I'm using Spring 3, and the type of the controller is @Controller

Comment: aService and saveOrUpdate are the type of Habilidad

Comment: How does your first jsp page is getting loaded, What is the URL ? Does it through Spring Controller?

Comment: It's loaded by the spring controller:  '@RequestMapping(value = "/habilidades", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getHabilidades(Model model)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442956/with-spring-3-annotations-jsr303-getting-neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target). You are missing the annotation `@modelAttribute` in your controller call.

```
public @ResponseBody Habilidad postHabilidades(@ModelAttribute Habilidad habilidad, HttpSession session)
```

Comment: Sorry but that does not fix the error. Continues with the same errors.

Comment: You also have a typo in your jsp `modalAttribute`. Remove the annotation and fix that.

Comment: Oh thanks! It's solves the error, but I couldn`t get he values of the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, replace

```
public @ResponseBody Habilidad postHabilidades(Habilidad habilidad, HttpSession session)
```

with

```
public @ResponseBody Habilidad postHabilidades(@ModelAttribute Habilidad habilidad, HttpSession session)
```

Comment: Sorry but that does not fix the error. Continues with the same errors.